# How to host multiple Provider Hosted App in Single App WebApp?

Tags: provider-hosted-app

The VS solutions is as below
App1
App2
Web1 >>Should be associated with App1
Web1 >>Should be associated with App2

How to host multiple Provider Hosted App in Single App WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

This is for SharePoint online low trust apps or on-prem high trust apps?

Also, what are you doing in your provider hosted component: handling app/item events OR showing some functionality on pages?

We have done this for a SP online app where we handle app install/uninstall/upgrade events for multiple Apps in same provider hosted component. Here you need to identify the App and based on that create the correct ClientContext using the TokenHelper class. We use AppEventProperties.ProductId to identify the App and then use the corresponding ClientId and Client Secret (so there is some change in web.config to have different Ids for each app and also corresponding change in generated TokenHelper class).

This should be possible in aspx pages as well, since you can identify the app from the query string parameters (SPAppWebUrl parameter will contain identifier for your app).